# Michael Hartl Tutorial 3.2 - Chapter 9 - Error Messages and Edit/Update page issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on Michael Hartl Rails 3.2 and I have been stuck with these issues for a few hours. I can't figure out what I am missing as I have gone through all of the code in 7, 8, 9 to make sure it is accurate.  The update/edit pages were working until I added in the private section in my user controls.

Since I added those in, when I manually test the page and hit settings, it goes straight to the signin page.  It seems like it isn't picking up on the unless signed_in? and redirecting it to the signing page from Users Controller page. It would make sense why my test are failing because the edit pages are not coming up to sign in. Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.  If you need to see other pages, let me know.

Error Messages - I get 9 errors like below

```
Failures:

1) UserPages edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
   expected css "h1" with text "Update your profile" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:73:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) UserPages edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails')}
   expected link "change" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:75:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) UserPages edit page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
   expected css "title" with text "Edit user" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:74:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

4) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

5) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

6) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

7) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

8) UserPages edit with valid information 
 Failure/Error: fill_in "Name", with: new_name
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label 'Name' found
 # (eval):2:in `fill_in'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

9) UserPages edit with invalid information 
 Failure/Error: before { click_button "Save changes" }
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no button with value or id or text 'Save changes' found
 # (eval):2:in `click_button'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:79:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the Authentication Spec Page

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "AuthenticationPages" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') } 
end

describe "signin" do
before { visit signin_path}

    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
            before { click_link "Home" }
            it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
        end
    end


    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before { sign_in user }


        describe "followed by signout" do
            before { click_link "Sign out" }
            it { should have_link('Sign in')}
        end

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

    end
end

describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

        describe "in the Users controller" do

            describe "visiting the edit page" do
                before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
                it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in' ) }
            end

            describe "submitting to the update action" do
                before { put user_path(user) }
                specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

And the User Pages Spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do

subject { page }

describe "profile page" do
    before { visit user_path(user) }
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user) }


    it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name)}
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end

describe "signup page" do
    before {visit signup_path}
    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up'))}
end

describe "signup" do
    before { visit signup_path}
    let(:submit) { "Create my account"}

    describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
        end

    describe "after submission" do
      before { click_button submit }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
      it { should have_content('error') }
    end
end

describe "with valid information" do
        before do
            fill_in "Name", with: "Exmaple User"
            fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
            fill_in "Password confirmation", with: "foobar"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end

    describe "after saving the user" do
      before { click_button submit }
      let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out') }
    end
    end
end


describe "edit" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before do
  visit signin_path
  sign_in user
  visit edit_user_path(user)
end


describe "page" do
  it { should have_selector('h1', text: "Update your profile") }
  it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
  it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails')}
end

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Save changes" }

  it { should have_content('error') }
end

describe "with valid information" do
    let(:new_name) { "New Name"}
    let(:new_email) {"new@example.com"}
    before do
      fill_in "Name", with: new_name
      fill_in "Email", with: new_email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Save changes"
    end

it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
specify { user.reload.name.should == new_name }
specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
end
end
end
```

The sign_in(user) from Utilities

```
def sign_in(user)
fill_in "Email", with: user.email
fill_in "Password", with: user.password
click_button "Sign in"
# Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

end

Sessions Helper

```
module SessionsHelper

def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
end

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
end

def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
end

def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end
end
```

Users Controller

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
    before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]

    def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
@user = User.new
    end

    def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
else
    render 'new'
end
   end

def edit
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   end

def update
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
     sign_in @user
     flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
     redirect_to @user
   else
     render 'edit'
   end
  end

private
 def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." 
  end
end

def correct_user
  @user=User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
end

end
```

views/layouts/_header.html.erb

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav pull-right">
                    <li><%= link_to "Home",  root_path %></li>
                    <li><%= link_to "Help",  help_path %></li>
                    <% if signed_in? %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Users", "#" %></li>
                        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Account <b class="caret"></b>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>    
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>
                                    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    <% else %>
                        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you run into this problem - make sure you don't have this in your application_controller. This was a very small error that caused me all kinds of grief.  Again - DO NOT USE THIS CODE….

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery
 include SessionsHelper

 private
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

end

Comment: Can you post the code for the failing test and any views/partials that should render?

Comment: Hey Pinny, I added the test specs and the 9 failing test.  What exactly do you mean views/partials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara don't find the email field.

Before to fill the sign in form you should go on it. Change you function like this :

```
def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email", with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

I assume than your form is correctly formed. You can add, after `visit signin_path`, `puts page.html` to see the html and `save_and_open_page` if launchy is installed.

Comment: that would probably work to fix the test but the test aren't the problem.  I don't think the code is recognizing the def sign in? in the User Controller from the sessions helper.  I can't figure out why it isn't skipping over the code in signed_in_user? in the User Controller.  This is stopping my edit page from coming up and keeps asking me to sign in when I hit settings in the layout.

Comment: I changed that in the test and now the user is signed in and I have the 9 failing test above because the edit page isn't loading as I described above.   Failed tests are updated…..

Comment: Can you check the current path? Just add `puts current_path` in your specs.

Comment: I added puts current_path to the User Pages Spec code after visit edit_user_path(user) and it is going to /signin which is the reason for the rest of the errors.

Comment: Are you sure than your use is valid and can be connected? You may forgot to activate it (if it need to be activated). You can checkit like this : `puts user.valid? puts user.active?`

Comment: I figured out the error.  At some point in the tutorial it had me add the code below to the application_controller and it wasn't supposed to be there     
   def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
   end